# Twig render in service not finding CSS if called by background process in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, assets, message-handlers

I have a service method that I call by a MessageHandler and by a Controller Action:

```php
class ReceiptService
{
    public function myMethod()
    {
        // ...
        $html = $this->twig->render('folder/file.html.twig', []);
        // ...
    }
}
```

In my twig template, I call some CSS files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>My title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/PDF/file.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

When I use the Controller Action, the twig template is able to find my CSS files. But when it's the MessageHandler that calls it, it does not find it unless I put `public/` before each href, e.G.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/PDF/file.css">`
```

I tried using `{{ asset() }}` without success.

Would you know why and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try with **absolute_url**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ absolute_url(asset('css/PDF/file.css')) }}">
```